# Cannot Change Image Position on Smaller Screen

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I would like to align on the right of the screen when the screen is small and align on the left on larger screens - I have the code below but not sure why this isn't working as expected:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 855px) {
  .left_logo {float: right;}
}

.left_logo {
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 4%;
left: 3%;

}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="left_logo">
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/G5oF0mhpOcQzFTrU6TDUL0JoAjzRt38weiZKua7L61WVT1z3dPcE9gUu-W2EwtM9cZU=s180-rw">
</div>

  
</body>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/oak22424/djbmqyk0/2/#&togetherjs=JRRSOGIcor

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Hi - sorry if not clear in the post, the div should have the image in it <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/G5oF0mhpOcQzFTrU6TDUL0JoAjzRt38weiZKua7L61WVT1z3dPcE9gUu-W2EwtM9cZU=s180-rw">

Comment: There's nothing to `float` off of. You need a sibling to let img in the sides of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `position:absolute` *and* `float` - its either one or the other.

As you want to position the image at a specific `top` and `left` value, then you can remove float and just use position: absolute. To move it to the right, you can set `right` to whatever value you want, and set `left` to `auto` to clear the previous value of 3%.

```
.left_logo {
  left:auto; /* reset the value for left */ 
  right:3%;
}
```

Also note that you also need to include the media query *after* the more general CSS, otherwise it will be overridden by the CSS that comes after it.

**Working snippet** based on your fiddle - view it in full screen to see the image move to the left:

```css
.left_logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    left: 3%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 855px) {
  .left_logo {
      left:auto; /* reset left value */
      right:3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="left_logo">
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/G5oF0mhpOcQzFTrU6TDUL0JoAjzRt38weiZKua7L61WVT1z3dPcE9gUu-W2EwtM9cZU=s180-rw">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you FluffyKitten, appreciate the follow-up and added tips.